# python twisted tutorial/question

Tags: python, client, twisted

Got a simple question regarding twisted.

I can create a trivial basic test with a web server like apache, where http://foo.com/index.php instantiates the index.php for the "foo" site/app...

I'm trying to figure out how the heck I can create a twisted server, where I run different backend functions based on the input!

I know, embarrasingly simple.. but none of what I've seen regarding twisted/server/client/etc.. discusses this.

Comments/pointers/samples are greatly welcome.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you read this?
http://krondo.com/blog/?page_id=1327

Comment: hey sheepz!

thanks. hadn't seen it. i'll take a good look at it..

tom

Answer (score 0):

You may find http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/web-in-60/index.html helpful.